# android app crashes due to firebase versions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm developing app that uses firebase as back-end here is my build.gradle file

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.0'
```

when i open the app it crashes here is my logcat `

```
08-26 12:29:33.886 32721-32754/com.example.fcb.dolaby E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
                                                                java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zza(Landroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcelable$Creator;)Landroid/os/Parcelable; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzeg; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeg' appears in /data/app/com.example.fcb.dolaby-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes6.dex)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaw.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:459)
                                                                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:512)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzay.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbw.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: clean project and re build, also please show the code where you are calling firebase. you have dependencies both for DB and auth which is the causing the problem

Comment: inside the oncreate method i only used firebase storage                       storage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference=storage.getReference().child("photos");
inside onclick i used    storageref.putfile(uri)

Answer (score 1):

Try change this:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
```

To this:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.1.1'
```

Or change this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.0'
```

To this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.0'
```

Acording to this:

**FirebaseUI Version** - **Firebase/Play Services Version**

> 2.3.0 - 11.0.4
>
> 2.2.0 - 11.0.4
>
> 2.1.1 - 11.0.2
>
> 2.0.1 - 11.0.1
>
> 1.2.0 - 10.2.0
>
> 1.1.1 - 10.0.0 or 10.0.1
>
> 1.0.1 - 10.0.0 or 10.0.1
>
> 1.0.0 - 9.8.0

You can read the full readme from this link [Firebase ui](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

Comment: when i added the the new versions it gave me inspection in     'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'   android support libraries must be exact same versions(mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)

Comment: what you tried the firist way, or the second way? @AbdelazizWaheedLasheen

Comment: I fixed this bug by choosing the correct versions of firebase and firebaseUi thanks for your help